# ODE and rate problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Hi I'm having some trouble with this problem. I found that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0.75r - \frac{Q(10+r)}{2}$$

where r = 20 which is correct, but I can't figure out how to finish the problem:

A mixing chamber initially contains $2$ liters of a clear liquid. Clear liquid flows into the chamber at a rate of $10$ liters per minute. A dye solution having a concentration of $0.75$ kilograms per liter is injected into the mixing chamber at a constant rate of $r$ liters per minute. When the mixing process is started, the well-stirred mixture is pumped from the chamber at a rate of $10+r$ liters per minute. Assume the mixing chamber contains $2$ liters of clear liquid at time $t = 0$.
How many minutes will it take for the outflow concentration to rise to within $5\%$ of the desired concentration of $0.5$ kilograms per liter?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to decide if $Q$ is the amount of dye in the chamber or if it is the concentration. In the second case you need to also divide the inflow amount by the chamber volume. This then results in the reported $r=20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $r=20$ into your ode

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0.75r - \frac{Q(10+r)}{2}$$

and rearrange it in the form below,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{ 1-Q} =15 \mathrm{d}t$$

Integrate with the initial value $Q(0) =0$

$$ -\ln (1-Q) = 15t$$

and get the solution

$$Q(t)= 1- e^{-15t}$$

The concentration of 0.5 kilogram per liter corresponds to $Q=1$. Then, the time it takes to reach within 5% of $Q=1$  satisfies

$$ 5\% = e^{-15t}$$

Solve to get

$$t= \frac{\ln20}{15}=0.2 \>\text{minute}$$

or, 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide if $Q$ is the amount of dye in the chamber or if it is the concentration. In the second case, the balance equation over some small time span $\Delta t$ reads
$$
{\rm vol}_{\rm chamber}\Delta Q = \Delta {\rm vol}_{\rm inflow 2}Q_{\rm inflow 2} - (\Delta {\rm vol}_{\rm inflow 1}+\Delta {\rm vol}_{\rm inflow 2})Q
$$
and by dividing by $\Delta t$ and going to the differentials
$$
2\dot Q = r\cdot 0.75-(10+r)Q.
$$
Thus to get to the correct equation you need to also divide the inflow amount by the chamber volume. This then results in the equilibrium at the reported $r=20$, so that the total inflow is $30Δt$ and the amount of dye in it $15Δt$, resulting in the desired half-and-half mix.

The equation $\dot Q=15(0.5-Q)$ solves as $0.5-Q(t)=(0.5-Q_0)e^{-15t}$, so that you need to solve $$e^{-15t}\le 0.05.$$